# Terraform 11 AWS RDS Upgrade Fails

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I am using Terraform v11 to upgrade DB's running on AWS RDS with MySql engine from v5.6 to v5.7.

Each of the DB's has it's own dedicated options group and parameter group.

The upgrade process fails with error:

```
aws_db_parameter_group.manager: Error deleting DB parameter group: InvalidDBParameterGroupState: One or more database instances are still members of this parameter group foo-rds-mysql56, so the group cannot be deleted
```

Is there any workaround for this?

##### Reply to [ydaetskcoR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291321/ydaetskcor):

The plan output is :

```
-/+ aws_db_parameter_group.foo (new resource required)
      id:                                "foo-mysql-56" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      arn:                               "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-2:238425939713:pg:foo-mysql-56" => <computed>
      description:                       "Managed by Terraform" => "Managed by Terraform"
      family:                            "mysql5.6" => "mysql5.7" (forces new resource)
      name:                              "foo-mysql-56" => "foo-mysql-57" (forces new resource)
      name_prefix:                       "" => <computed>
      parameter.#:                       "1" => "1"
      parameter.2547865204.apply_method: "pending-reboot" => "pending-reboot"
      parameter.2547865204.name:         "max_connections" => "max_connections"
      parameter.2547865204.value:        "128" => "128"
```

Comment: What does the plan show? Also Terraform 0.12 came out very nearly 2 years ago and includes a major improvement to HCL and Terraform in general (although granted, also the most awkward upgrade of all the major bumps) so you should strongly consider upgrading.

Comment: As this question is not about programming, it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO provides help in database admin type of questions like this one.